# Help me get started with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I've looked through the documentation on the web site and it is written as if you already know how to use it, in other words it might as well be in Chinese. With that being said, I downloaded it, now what? There is no exe, it looks like it needs to be compiled... How do I do that?

I've made about 30 different google searches on getting started with it but no luck.

I've never had this much trouble working with a third party component.

Comment: You can get windows and macos binaries from here:  http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/ so you don't have to build it yourself.  Once you have the exe, what exactly are you wanting to do?  ffmpeg can do a ton of things and it would help if you could narrow it down.

Comment: What OS are you using? What is the intended use of ffmpeg in your case?

Comment: I'm using windows and I plan to use ColdFusion to invoke ffmpeg, to make a thumbnail image of a previously saved .flv video. Someone told me how to do it with ColdFusion but there is no .exe in the ffmpeg folder to point to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working from an answer in another question:

```
<cfexecute 
name="c:\pathto\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"
arguments="-itsoffset -4  -i #sourcevideo# -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 #thumbnaildestination" />
```

Thanks to Jason for pointing me to the autobuilds link. I was scratching my head trying to figure out what to do with the files.